# Changing number VUs doesn't affect number of actual number of http requests sent in k6 load test

Tags: testing, load-testing, k6

So, I started from 1 VU, and ended with 199, after that value of VUs number of checks doesn't grow up anymore.

So, I tried this

```
import http from "k6/http";
import { check } from "k6";

export const options = {
  scenarios: { default: {
  executor: 'constant-arrival-rate',
  duration: '30s',
  rate: 5000, timeUnit: '1s',
  preAllocatedVUs: 900
  } }
};

export default function() {
  const res = http.get("http://ipv4:6399/game_heartbeat");
  check(res, { "status was 200": r => r.status == 200 })
};
```

got

> WARN[0002] Insufficient VUs, reached 900 active VUs and cannot
> initialize more  executor=constant-arrival-rate scenario=default
>
> running (0m30.0s), 000/900 VUs, 128808 complete and 0 interrupted
> iterations default ✓ [======================================] 000/900
> VUs  30s  5000 iters/s

Tried

```
import http from "k6/http";
import { check } from "k6";

export const options = {
  vus: 199,
  duration: "30s"
};

export default function() {
  const res = http.get("http://ipv4:6399/game_heartbeat");
  check(res, { "status was 200": r => r.status == 200 })
};
```

and got

> running (0m30.0s), 000/199 VUs, 163220 complete and 0 interrupted
> iterations default ↓ [======================================] 199 VUs
> 30s
>
> ```
>  ✓ status was 200
>
>  checks.........................: 100.00% ✓ 163220      ✗ 0
> ```

if I change VUs from 199 to 299, 399, 699 - it doesn't change number of checks. It still would be somewhere around 165k for 30s run

My version is k6 v0.36.0 (2022-01-24T09:50:03+0000/ff3f8df, go1.17.6, linux/amd64)

I am running the script without any additional params, just like `k6 run script.js`

How I could increase 'pressure' from k6 on a testing service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options are in:

1. The testing service cannot handle more requests that you're sending, i.e. you reached the [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing), in that case you should start looking for the reason and for the ways of improving the service performance
2. k6 is not capable of sending more requests because it lacks resources like CPU, RAM, network IO, etc. In that case you can either consider moving your load generator to a more powerful machine or consider switching to a load testing tool like [JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/) or [Locust](https://docs.locust.io/en/v0.8/running-locust-distributed.html) which support distributed execution mode.

Comment: 1) But if the service reached the top of it's abilities, should I get some errors from the backend? If I increase VUs even more, to 1500, I starting to get errors up to 70% of checks. 2) It is still capable to spawn more VUs. Dunno, could the application spawn the VU, but not use it, in case of the resources of k6's machine being in deficit?